# Using chokidar watch file, RegEx for param `ignored` is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, chokidar

I am using chokidar to watch files ending with (.js|.jsx|.scss) as below, but RegEx does not work. if just run `/^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$/`, it works fine.

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch('./app', {
      ignored: /^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$/,
      ignoreInitial: true,
      persistent: true
})
```

Comment: I think this is the _ignored_ stuff. So, if it matches it is ignored. If you want to ignore these file extensions, try `(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)` or `(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chokidar watches files, also watches paths. So `/^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$/` would ignore files not ending with .js/jsx/.scss but also all paths. To resolve this problem, I use below RegEx:

```
/^(?=.*(\.\w+)$)(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$/
```